# Fatal error: Call to undefined function in PHP

Tags: php, function

I have the following code for the payment section of PHP website

```
if (isset($_POST['Confirm'])) {

  $payment = $_SESSION['payment'];
  $paymode = checkpaymentmode($payment); //get paymentmode code
  $mtxcd = getmtxcd(); //merchant transaction code


  if (!function_exists('checkpaymentmode')) {
        function checkpaymentmode($payment) {
            if ($payment == 'Amex') {
                return "A";
            } elseif ($payment == 'Direc-Debit') {
                return "D";
            } else {
                return "C";
            } //assume the rest are visa/master
        }

    }

}
```

This code is the part one confirmation page. After confirmation, execute these codes. Am using some other functions in this page along with this function. I comment this one and try with others, got same error with all functions.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function checkpaymentmode() in line33..

Any solution for this??

Comment: think line by line, logically. you are checking if the function exists *after* calling it. Also read the error message. It is actually telling you how to solve this problem; by defining the function `checkpaymentmode()`, which is actually a pretty big hint :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the function

```
$paymode = checkpaymentmode($payment); //get paymentmode code
```

before it is defined.

Add the function before the function is called like,

```
if (!function_exists('checkpaymentmode')) {   // define the fucntion
        function checkpaymentmode($payment) {
            if ($payment == 'Amex') {
                return "A";
            } elseif ($payment == 'Direc-Debit') {
                return "D";
            } else {
                return "C";
            } //assume the rest are visa/master
        }

    }

if (isset($_POST['Confirm'])) {

  $payment = $_SESSION['payment'];
  $paymode = checkpaymentmode($payment); //get paymentmode code
  $mtxcd = getmtxcd(); //merchant transaction code
  --------------------------
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the function before it is defined, you need to move your IF clause for defining the function to the top, likewise

```
if (isset($_POST['Confirm'])) {
  if (!function_exists('checkpaymentmode')) {
        function checkpaymentmode($payment) {
            if ($payment == 'Amex') {
                return "A";
            } elseif ($payment == 'Direc-Debit') {
                return "D";
            } else {
                return "C";
            } //assume the rest are visa/master
        }

    }

  $payment = $_SESSION['payment'];
  $paymode = checkpaymentmode($payment); //get paymentmode code
  $mtxcd = getmtxcd(); //merchant transaction code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function before you implement it. Shift these code

```
  $payment = $_SESSION['payment'];
  $paymode = checkpaymentmode($payment); //get paymentmode code
  $mtxcd = getmtxcd(); //merchant transaction code
```

below the function and it should work.